# Want to show Filter Data in DevExpress GridControl when I repoen the page

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have `DevExpress GridControl` in my MVC application along with simple search box to search and filter the values on all GridControl's string columns.

Here, I need to show the filtered text (search text) and filtered values on the `GridControl` once after I attempt to reopen the form. May I know, how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@subash

Please try this

you can enable the following `properties`, you can solve the problem

```
gridName.SettingsCookies.Enabled = true;
gridName.SettingsCookies.CookiesID = "YourCoookiesName";
gridName.SettingsCookies.StoreColumnsVisiblePosition = true;
gridName.SettingsCookies.StoreColumnsWidth = true;
gridName.SettingsCookies.StoreFiltering = true;
gridName.SettingsCookies.StoreGroupingAndSorting = true;
gridName.SettingsCookies.StorePaging = true;
```